# Chrome Devtools Perfomance profiler dump json file parser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, v8, stack-trace, web-performance

I'm trying to **parse the results of the performance profiler tool**, but I've googled everything and I cannot find anything. [Where to dump profiler jsonfile Sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qcDr.png)

The only documentation I've found so far is related to Events events, and I've finished implementing them. Although this is also outdated, it seems to be sufficient for now.

I manage to parse **Frames、Interactions and Stacktrace&Browser activity Flamechart** [Sample picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG09s.jpg). From my observation of the logs, it seems that only two process ids (**`pid`** fields) in all logs need to be filtered.

I tried clustering on the `args` parameters to see how to go through these detailed parameters to draw the flamechart, but so far I don't understand any of the fields in the `args` . My parsing python code and cleaned profiler json file can be seen in this github: [ChromePerformanceProfilerParser](https://github.com/NITROGENousFish/ChromePerformanceProfilerParser)

I would like to know if there is any documentation or tools about **chrome performance profiler** , or if this feature is in some Chrome open source project.

Thanks A Lot !!!

Comment: Chrome is using Chromium and its devtools, which is open source, so try inspecting the code.

Comment: I've looked at the official Chromium source code, I searched their repository globally for "devtools", "performance" and "profiler"; but didn't find any useful information. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know if there is any documentation or tools about chrome performance profiler

Yes: [this document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CvAClvFfyA5R-PhYUmn5OOQtYMH4h6I0nSsKchNAySU/preview) describes the trace file format, [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QADiFe0ss7Ydq-LUNOPpIf6z4KXGuWs_ygxiJxoMZKo/edit) gives an overview of "the profiler".

> or if this feature is in some Chrome open source project.

Yes: https://chromium.googlesource.com/catapult/+/HEAD/tracing/README.md

Comment: Thanks! I have implemented the resolution of all Event types in the first document, which is already available in the Github repository mentioned in my question. [link here](https://github.com/NITROGENousFish/ChromePerformanceProfilerParser/blob/main/v8profilerspecfication.py) if anyone need it.

I've never seen the last two links in my searches, I'll look into it!!!

Comment: Hi @jmrk . The overall workflow of catapult Profiler is to put a lot of predefined parsing scripts under the `tracing/tracing/` path and assemble them after inputting the profiler json file (generating an html file consisting entirely of various scripts internally, with the compressed json trace at the bottom of the script). I tried to locate the main parsing entry `/tracing/tracing/extras/importer/trace_event_importer.html`, but the internal processing is very cumbersome. Do you know any further documentation of  parsing chrome profiling json files? or I'll just have to read these JS scripts.

Comment: @NitrogenousFish I don't know any further documentation, sorry. I think reading the source is your best bet. In fact, maybe modifying the existing code to add/change whatever features you have in mind is less work than reimplementing everything from scratch?