# How to convert Google Chrome's Devtools Perfomance profiler json data dump to diagrams like .puml?

Tags: json, google-chrome, visualization, diagram, google-developer-tools

I've stumbled across this question [Chrome Devtools Perfomance profiler dump json file parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71454764/chrome-devtools-perfomance-profiler-dump-json-file-parser) and the links posted there pointed me to [Catapult](https://chromium.googlesource.com/catapult/+/HEAD/tracing/README.md) project.

I did cloned the sources of Catapult and converted the exported earlier recorded profiles of Developer Tools Performance tab as html webpages (JSON to HTML) using `$CATAPULT/tracing/bin/trace2html my_trace.json --output=my_trace.html && open my_trace.html`  command.

But the result [far from I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1mQ2.png).

What I'm looking for is ability to convert certain - chosen by me, which will be only calls to methods used during logout from my profiled application - parts of dumped JSON data into visual diagrams, either tree or top-to-bottom, especially with option to export this into .puml code language.

Have anyone knows any type of services or apps helpful in converting the Google Chrome's Developer Tools Performance profile's tracing data dump, into visual diagrams or how could I achieve this using Catapult tool?